# Why ROS_Kinetic is recommended Distribution?

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and my Kinetic does not work anymore,

> Unable to locate package
> ros-kinetic-desktop-full

When I see list of distribution [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)

Why (recommended) is written infront of Kinetic ?

Why not melodic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301476/why-ros_kinetic-is-recommended-distribution-?/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2018-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With Ubuntu 18.04 you should use [ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic) as it is primarily targeted at the Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) release. I guess when all the packages are added and since it will have a long term support it will become recommended at some point. At the moment ROS Kinetic is the most used one and has a number of packages that are probably still not ported to the newer distributions.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4